# Perl: import shell variable

Tags: perl, shell, environment-variables, csh

In shell, I had sourced `.cshrc` file which contains some defined variables like user name.

I need to pass these variables to a certain Perl script.

**For example** in shell terminal, I typed

`>echo $user`

The output is `>esaad`

Then in Perl, to read `$user` variable, I tried:

`system("echo $user")`

Also tried this command:

`my $userName = system(` `echo $ENV{user}` `);`

but Perl asked for `$user` initialization as Perl variable not Shell one.

How I could read this variable?

Comment: Are the variables environment variables or shell variables?  If they are shell variables you won't be able to access them from Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

```
print $ENV{'user'}
```

the reason your system call doesn't work is that system open a new shell that doesn't source .cshrc
read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225102/which-shell-does-a-perl-system-call-use) answer for more information

Answer (score 0):

Either use Perl built-in system variable $ENV:

```
print $ENV{'user'}
```

Or use backslash to escape the variable $user.  Perl will interpret for $user variable defined inside the Perl program without the backslash. With backslash, "echo $user" is passed as system call.

```
system("echo \$user")
```

Comment: or, use single quotes: `system('echo $user')`