# forcing brace expansion in backticks or why is this inconsistent?

Tags: bash, shell, perl, tcsh

When using backticks (in perl) i seem to have some sort of inconsistency with brace expansion

```
print `ls -d ~/{a,b}`;
```

Works fine, but when i try

```
print `ls -d ~/{a}`;
```

I get:

> ```
> ls: cannot access /home/user/{a}: No such file or directory
> ```

I have tried all sort of quoting, spacing  and escapes but to no avail. my question is, is there a way to force the expansion? I realize I can avoid the issue all together if I just glob the stuff myself, but I'm curious about this behavior

i tried this under both bash and tcsh. when used directly under tcsh, the command works, but under bash it doesn't

Comment: `bash` and `tcsh` are two *completely* different shells; which are you actually using?

Comment: `print` isn't even a valid `bash` command

Comment: @chepner this is perl...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now, after your several edits, I understand that you may be using two different shells. And, also, that the one calling the shell is perl, not you.

So, to cover the three elements:

### bash

In bash. A simple {a} will not be expanded:

```
$ echo ~/{a,b}
/home/user/a /home/user/b

$ echo ~/{a}
/home/user/{a}
```

Which is searched as a file by `ls`, and not found.

The relevant part of the manual man bash is (emphasis mine):

> A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted **opening and closing braces**, and at least **one unquoted comma** or a valid sequence expression.

A `{a}` is lacking a required comma.

The only alternative is to actually use

```
$ print `ls -d ~/a`
```

### tcsh

In `tcsh`: A simple {a} will be expanded (as in a `csh` shell):
Using `>` as shell indicator for tcsh prompt:

```
> echo --{a,b}++
 --a++ --b++

> echo --{a}++
--a++
```

As a simple `{}` also will:

```
$ echo --{}++
 --++
```

The only braces that will **not** be removed will be `{}` and `{` and `}`.
*IIF* (if and only if) they are recognized as "words". Most commonly surrounded by spaces:

```
$ echo --{}++ == {} .. { :: } aa { bb
--++ == {} .. { :: } aa { bb
```

If a `{` or a `}` appear as *part* of a word, without the matching brace, is an error:

```
> echo aa{bb
Missing '}'.
```

The only description of this on the [man tcsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) is really short (unclear?):

```
> As a special case the words `{', `}' and `{}' are passed undisturbed.
```

### perl

If the shell commands are [called from perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4225709/8017719), in the cases that do call a shell, like under Unix systems, the shell called is `/bin/sh`.

An an additional twist, the `/bin/sh` is served by bash in most linux systems, by [tcsh in FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/linux-users/shells.html) and by [ksh or csh in OpenBSD](http://daemonforums.org/showpost.php?s=bf0ccfd7a188842b32eb8f1044c43016&p=6544&postcount=3).

It becomes difficult to predict the output of a perl called `/bin/sh`.

You could make sure that an specific shell is called:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print `/bin/tcsh -c 'ls -d ~/{a,b}'`;
```

Now the question remains:

- Why do you need to use brace expansion on a single character?

Comment: unfortunately i  wont have access to the system untill next week, but i understand the issue is that doing 'ls -d ~/{a}' in the shell actually works. i will mark this as solved for now and update next week. thanks!

Comment: Re "*doing 'ls -d ~/{a}' in the shell actually works*", Did you actually use `/bin/sh`?

Comment: @arrow upon further inspection it seems that under tcsh the ls works, but under bash it does NOT. why though, while using perl under tcsh doesnt it work?

Comment: Perl doesn't care what shell you are using. Backticks uses /bin/sh.

Comment: @Nullman Expanded sections for tcsh and perl. All the details should be clear now. Any additional question?.

Comment: @Arrow excellent and complete answer! the answer to your question is that i dont! im not even using ls. i just gave that as a simple example to a more complex command invocation :)

Comment: Really, the answer to @isaac's question (because I've encountered this issue before) is that sometimes the pattern inside the curries is programmatically created, e.g. by a join on a list of items, where the size of the list is variable/unpredictable. I'm also a tcsh user and to me, I agree with OP that bash brace expansion is inconsistent. Not only do you have to create a special case for an empty list, you have to create one for a list size of 1. Incidentally OP, I use `bsd_glob` wrapped in some customizing code for the remaining quirks for all shell interpolations in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

When you are having problems with shell commands, try them outside of Perl (or any program) to see what they do:

Bash:

```
$ ls ~/{a}
ls: /Users/brian/{a}: No such file or directory
$ ls ~/{a,b}
ls: /Users/brian/a: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/brian/b: No such file or directory
```

Tsch:

```
% ls ~/{a}
ls: /Users/brian/a: No such file or directory
% ls ~/{a,b}
ls: /Users/brian/a: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/brian/b: No such file or directory
```

So, you see that the two shells expand globs differently. From the [bash docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and closing braces, and at least one unquoted comma or a valid sequence expression. Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged.

From the [tcsh docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) is a bit lacking in that it doesn't mention that you don't need the comma for expansion:

> The metanotation 'a{b,c,d}e' is a shorthand for 'abe ace ade'. Left-to-right order is preserved: '/usr/source/s1/{oldls,ls}.c' expands to '/usr/source/s1/oldls.c /usr/source/s1/ls.c'. The results of matches are sorted separately at a low level to preserve this order: '../{memo,*box}' might expand to '../memo ../box ../mbox'. (Note that 'memo' was not sorted with the results of matching '*box'.) It is not an error when this construct expands to files which do not exist, but it is possible to get an error from a command to which the expanded list is passed. This construct may be nested. As a special case the words '{', '}' and '{}' are passed undisturbed.

Now, inside Perl, the backticks use */bin/sh*. It doesn't care which shell you were in when you started the *perl* process. From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> A string which is (possibly) interpolated and then executed as a system command with /bin/sh or its equivalent.

That's why you see the bash behavior. However, you can use any shell that you like (and is available on the system):

```
my $output = `tcsh -c 'ls -l ~/{a}'`
```

Comment: upon further read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225102/which-shell-does-a-perl-system-call-use it seems you are correct! thank you!

Comment: Well, since I cite the actual perl docs, I'm also technically correct, which is the best kind of correct. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo