# How make open function use bash instead of sh?

Tags: bash, perl, pipe

I want to use `bash` instead of `sh` when I use the `open` function. For instance:

```
sub run_cmd {
    my ($cmd) = @_;
    my $fcmd;

    print("Run $cmd\n");

    open($fcmd, "$cmd |");
    while ( my $line = <$fcmd> ) {
        print "-> $line";
    }
    close $fcmd;
}

eval{run_cmd('ps -p $$')};
```

Here, the output is:

```
Run ps -p $$
->    PID TTY          TIME CMD
-> 189493 pts/6    00:00:00 sh
```

We can see `sh` is used by default.

I have some constraints and I need (1) to use the open function and (2) to call `bash` instead of `sh`. I tried simply to add `bash` at the beginning of my command but it doesn't work:

```
Run ps -p $$
/bin/ps: /bin/ps: cannot execute binary file
```

What can I do to use `bash` with the `open` function?

Comment: A related question that may help you: [Which shell does a Perl system() call use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4225102/7939871)

Comment: @Pierre : Aside from the correct answer given by tripleee, the error you see comes probably from an incorrect setting of the `PATH` environment variable. I suggest that, for testing, you print its value before running the command.

Comment: @user1934428 No, putting `bash` immediately in front will simply cause `bash` to try to execute `ps` as a script file.

Comment: @tripleee - Right, I should have read the error message properly. Or course the `-c` is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't take your chances with quote injections:

```
open my $fcmd, '-|', qw(bash -c), $cmd;
```

(Also notice that you don't need to close `$fcmd` explicitly if you declared it with `my`; it will be automatically closed at the end of the block; perl is not java ;-))

Answer (score 5):

You can explicitly run `bash` instead.

```perl
open($fcd, "bash -c '$cmd' |");
```

The other answer indeed shows some important best practices for when `cmd` is not completely trivial, or not under your control.

Comment: That will still call `sh -c` to run the `bash -c` (because of the single quotes).